# Extract data with soup

Tags: java, jsoup

I am using jsoup to extract info from a web, my code is like this:

```
doc = Jsoup.connect(myurl).get();
            Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select(".myclass");
```

If I do a System.out.println of newsHeadlines I obtain this:

```
<span class="cmtComentario">
<span class="blaicon"></span>
<span class="blacoment"><span class="cmtHora" data-hora=""></span>
<span class="blathing" data-minutoPartido="93'"></span>
<span class="blado"></span>
<span class="blahave">
Oh yeah!<br/></span>
</span>
</span>
<span class="cmtComentario">
<span class="blaicon"></span>
<span class="blacoment"><span class="cmtHora" data-hora=""></span>
<span class="blathing" data-health="97'"></span>
<span class="blado"></span>
<span class="blahave">
This is my world</span>
</span>
</span>
```

How can I save on array each block:

```
<span class="cmtComentario">
    <span class="blaicon"></span>
    <span class="blacoment"><span class="cmtHora" data-hora=""></span>
    <span class="blathing" data-health="92'"></span>
    <span class="blado"></span>
    <span class="blahave">
    This is my world</span>
    </span>
    </span>
```

Thank you so much

Comment: I want to save this block of string on an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`newsHeadlines` is nothing else than a List of [Element](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html) as [Elements](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html) implements List.

So you can iterate over the `newsHeadlines` the same way than you iterate over a list.

```
for(Element element : newsHeadlines) {
    System.out.println(element.toString());
}
```

If that is not what you need (I did not test the code), you can try [Element.children](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#children%28%29).
This gives you again Elements you can iterate over.

Answer (score 0):

You could also add a div tag for each comment, and use some Java 8 syntax sugar for collecting the `Element`-instances in a `List`

```
    Elements elements = Jsoup.parse(markup).getAllElements().select(".myclass");
    List<Element> comments = elements.stream().collect(Collectors.<Element>toList());
    for(Element comment : comments)  {
        System.out.println(comment.html());
    }
```

For the sake of the test I used parse, instead of the connect-method.

It prints:

```
<span class="cmtComentario"> <span class="blaicon">1</span>.......
<span class="cmtComentario"> <span class="blaicon">2</span>........
```

Test markup:

```
String markup = "" +
        "<div class=\"myclass\">\n" +
            "<span class=\"cmtComentario\">\n" +
            "<span class=\"blaicon\">1</span>\n" +
            "<span class=\"blacoment\"><span class=\"cmtHora\" data-hora=\"\"></span>\n" +
            "<span class=\"blathing\" data-minutoPartido=\"93'\"></span>\n" +
            "<span class=\"blado\"></span>\n" +
            "<span class=\"blahave\">\n" +
            "Oh yeah!<br/></span>\n" +
            "</span>\n" +
            "</span>\n" +
        "</div>" +
        "<div class=\"myclass\">\n" +
            "<span class=\"cmtComentario\">\n" +
            "<span class=\"blaicon\">2</span>\n" +
            "<span class=\"blacoment\"><span class=\"cmtHora\" data-hora=\"\"></span>\n" +
            "<span class=\"blathing\" data-health=\"97'\"></span>\n" +
            "<span class=\"blado\"></span>\n" +
            "<span class=\"blahave\">\n" +
            "This is my world</span>\n" +
            "</span>\n" +
            "</span>" +
        "</div>";
```

Hope it helps!